# Formatting the response of date()

Tags: php, date

The function `date("y-M-d H:m:s")` returns 12-Jul-23 19:07:35.

But I need it to return 2012-07-23 19:07:35.

How do write 07 instead of Jul and 2012 instead of 12 (yyyy does no do this).

Comment: Did you check the [PHP docs entry for `date()`](http://www.php.net/date)?

Comment: Why is there a downvote for this question? The asker clearly does not know the answer, and it is a perfectly valid question, so why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
date("Y-m-d H:m:s")
```

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/date

- Y    A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
- m    Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
- d    Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is date('Y-m-d H:m:s')